# How can I disable touch "actions" (scrolling, selecting cells) of a tableView while still allowing the possibility to select it?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a overlayView that usually covers the bottom 10% of a tableView.

[image: tableView and overlayView, resting state]

When I tap anywhere on the overlayView, the view slides up and covers 50% of the tableView.

[image: view is selected]

At the second (selected) state, I want to be able to go back to the first state by touching anywhere on the tableView, outside of the overlayView.

However, I want scrolling on the tableView (and any other action such as selecting a row) to be disabled until the view is back at the resting (bottom 10%) state.

Please ignore the "Edit" and "add" buttons, consider them disabled.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend [Sandro Pennisi](https://twitter.com/sandropennisi) provided me an answer on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/sandropennisi/status/781071917839253504) that I feel is the best one.

You basically add a transparent UIButton between the main view and the overlay view. It is usually disabled; then, when the overlayView has been slid up you "enable" the button and it start listening for touches. When a touch hits it, it moves the overlayView down in its default position.

[image: image of transparent uibutton]

Answer (score 0):

You can create an overlay that covers all the screen, but the upper part of it is transparent. Then add a tap gesture to the transparent part which will resize the overlay to the original position.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question an understand it well., I would like to tell you that you can use a bool to control animations and check your overlay view's state.

Steps :

1. take a bool as a member variable in you class and by default set it false.

   BOOL isOverlayViewAnimating = false;
2. in table view's delegate method :

   func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)
   {
       if(isOverlayViewAnimating == false) 
       {
           // do your stuff here
       }
   }
3. As table view is a subclass of uiscrollview, you can implement methods of that delegate too so check for bool in scrollview delegate methods as needed.
4. finally when begin animation set

   isOverlayViewAnimating = true;
   UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: 
   {
   //set your view's position here. 
   }, 
   completion:
   {
   (value: Bool)
   isOverlayViewAnimating = false;
   })

By this way you can control behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
1. Disable user interaction on table view
2. Start animating overlay view
3. Check for animation end, 
4. When animation ends for overlay view, enable user interaction on table view.
```